# Cant use buttons whilst timer is active

Tags: python, pysimplegui

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from time import time

q1 = [
        [sg.Text("Question 1!"), sg.Text("Time:"), sg.Text(" ", size=(20,1), key="t")],
        [sg.Text("This is where question 1 will be?"), sg.Button("Start")],
        [sg.Button("Option 1", key="1",button_color=("#ffffff","#151515"), disabled=True, enable_events=True), sg.Button("Option 2", key="2",button_color=("#00ff00", "#151515"), disabled=True)],
        [sg.Button("Option 3", key="3",button_color=("#00ffff","#151515"), disabled=True), sg.Button("Option 4", key="4",button_color=("#ff00ff", "#151515"), disabled=True)],
        [sg.Button("Submit"), sg.Button("Next Question"), sg.Button("Skip")]
    ]

window = sg.Window("Question 1",q1)

while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event is None:
        break

    if event == "1":
        sg.popup("Test 1")
    elif event == "2":
        sg.popup("Test 2")
    elif event == "3":
            sg.popup("Test 3")
    elif event == "4":
        sg.popup("Test 4")

    if event == "Start":
        window.FindElement('1').Update(disabled=False)
        window.FindElement('2').Update(disabled=False)
        window.FindElement('3').Update(disabled=False)
        window.FindElement('4').Update(disabled=False)
        window.FindElement("Start").Update(visible=False)
        window.Refresh()

        seconds = 6

        start = time()
        current = time()
        timeleft = seconds

        while timeleft > 0:
            window.FindElement("t").Update(timeleft)
            window.refresh()
            current = time()
            timeleft = int(seconds - (current - start))
            if timeleft == 0:
                sg.popup("no time left")
```

I want to make it so that whilst the timer is active, the buttons can be pressed to get the answer the user has chosen. However, the answer is only gotten once the timer has ended. 
It is for a quiz, so I want to make the program have a timer for each question for the user to answer within, if they dont answer, they lose a point and move on to the next question. I have the overall template functioning, however this is the only aspect i cannot seem to grasp.
At the moment i am not even sure if what i am desiring is posible so any feedbvack or working arounds would be helpful

Comment: Don't run 2 event loops.  Add a timeout to your main event loop and then use a variable to indicate that the timer is active. If it is, then display values for it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from time import time,sleep
import threading


def start_timer(seconds):
    start = time()
    current = time()
    timeleft = seconds

    while timeleft > 0:
        window.write_event_value("update-time",timeleft)
        sleep(1)
        timeleft-=1
        if timeleft == 0:
            window.write_event_value("update-time",timeleft)
            window.write_event_value("timeout",timeleft)
            return


q1 = [
    [sg.Text("Question 1!"), sg.Text("Time:"), sg.Text(" ", size=(20, 1), key="t")],
    [sg.Text("This is where question 1 will be?"), sg.Button("Start")],
    [sg.Button("Option 1", key="1", button_color=("#ffffff", "#151515"), disabled=True, enable_events=True),
     sg.Button("Option 2", key="2", button_color=("#00ff00", "#151515"), disabled=True)],
    [sg.Button("Option 3", key="3", button_color=("#00ffff", "#151515"), disabled=True),
     sg.Button("Option 4", key="4", button_color=("#ff00ff", "#151515"), disabled=True)],
    [sg.Button("Submit"), sg.Button("Next Question"), sg.Button("Skip")]
]

window = sg.Window("Question 1", q1)

while True:
    event, values = window.Read()

    if event is None:
        break

    if event == "1":
        sg.popup("Test 1")
    elif event == "2":
        sg.popup("Test 2")
    elif event == "3":
        sg.popup("Test 3")
    elif event == "4":
        sg.popup("Test 4")

    if event == "Start":
        window.FindElement('1').Update(disabled=False)
        window.FindElement('2').Update(disabled=False)
        window.FindElement('3').Update(disabled=False)
        window.FindElement('4').Update(disabled=False)
        window.FindElement("Start").Update(visible=False)
        window.Refresh()

        seconds = 6
        t = threading.Thread(target=start_timer,args=[seconds])
        t.start()
    if event=="update-time":
        window.FindElement("t").Update(values["update-time"])
    if event=="timeout":
        sg.popup("timeout")
```

Comment: You cannot make any PySimpleGUI calls from a thread except for `write_event_value`.  All other calls are not allowed.

Comment: i'm not call PySimpleGUI  from the thread . i'm done the thread and then i call PySimpleGUI  from the main

Comment: Every time you call a method for the `window` object, you're calling PySimpleGUI.  refresh, FindElement, update... these are all calls into PySimpleGUI.  Not allowed.

Comment: It works, sometimes, until it doesn't.  tkinter is not thread-safe.  Working once, or twice, or 1,000 times doesn't make it ok to do.  Read the docs.

Comment: I'm change the answer.the thread use only write_event_value.

Comment: That would be much better (thumbs up) It's your only "legal" choice if calling from a thread.  I don't think a thread is needed if the event loop was run with a timeout instead of running 2 event loops.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223988/discussion-between-matan-h-and-mikeyb).